# How to access record inside Edit function without having to use <SimpleForm>?

Tags: react-admin

I have a `<Ressource>` declared as follows in **App.tsx**:

```
<Resource name="myresource" list={ListGuesser} edit={GenericEdit}/>
```

The code for **GenericEdit**:

```
const GenericEdit = function (props) {
    console.log('props', props);
    console.log('useResourceContext()', useResourceContext());
    console.log('useRecordContext()', useRecordContext());
    return (
        <>
            <Edit {...props}>
                <SimpleForm>
                    <TextInput disabled label="Id" source="id" />
                    <TextInput label="Name" source="name" />
                </SimpleForm>
            </Edit>
        </>)
};
export default GenericEdit;
```

**The `<Edit><SimpleForm>` default setup works well** (ie the record data is rendered inside the form), however I'd like to be able to use the `record` data my own way:

- `props` only contains metadata (URL path, resource type etc...) + record id, but no other record data
- `useResourceContext()` returns the resource type ("campaign" in my case)
- **`useRecordContext()` returns nothing**

---

**Q: How can I access the record data within my edit function (`GenericEdit`) without having to rely on the default `<SimpleForm>` functionality?**

Comment: have you looked at the different dataprovider hooks? in this case probably useGetOne would be useful to look up the details for one record: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#using-the-data-provider-in-components

and more information here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html

Comment: Problem is that `dataProvider` will already make 1 request by default since we're going to the the `edit` list, so that would make another unnecessary request for data we should already have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from React admin support, **which works for me**:

> The Edit component fetches the data and passes it to its children. In
> order to access fetch data, you would have to add an intermediate
> component and use the `useRecordContext` hook.

```
const MyForm = props => {
    const record = useRecordContext(props);
    console.log({ record });
    return (
        <>
            {/* We can still use the built-in React Admin */}
            <SimpleForm {...props}>
                <TextInput source="id" />
            </SimpleForm>
            {/* Or use something custom */}
            <div>{JSON.stringify(record)}</div>
        </>
    );
};

const GenericEdit = props => (
    // Here, the data hasn't been fetched yet 
    <Edit {...props} >
        <MyForm />
    </Edit>
);
export default GenericEdit;
```

Comment: You seem to want to receive data without using <Edit> and <SimpleForm>?

Comment: Initially yes because I thought I'm was going to get stuck with doing it the react-admin way. But it turns out once you're in `<Edit>` you have `record` and do whatever you want with it. I'm going to rephrase the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the source code of the Edit and EditView components to implement your form display. In the source text, you can see that it is Edit that provides the transfer of record data: [Edit.tsx](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/detail/Edit.tsx), [EditView.tsx](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/detail/EditView.tsx)

```
export const Edit = ( props: EditProps & { children: ReactElement } ): ReactElement => {

    useCheckMinimumRequiredProps('Edit', ['children'], props);
    const controllerProps = useEditController(props);

    const body = (
        <EditContextProvider value={controllerProps}>       
            <EditView {...props} {...controllerProps} /> // Your component for displaying form            
        </EditContextProvider>
    );

    return props.resource ? (
        // support resource override via props
        <ResourceContextProvider value={props.resource}>
            {body}
        </ResourceContextProvider>
    ) : (
        body
    );
};
```